# Add member to Azure DevOps team

Tags: powershell, command-line, tfs, azure-devops

I've able to get team or team member but I could not find away to add user to the team. Is there RESt_API, command line, or API that I could add user to the team using domain name "domain\user". Please advise. Great appreciate

Best Regards,

Comment: Which version?  Azure DevOps Services?  Did you already look at the [API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/memberentitlementmanagement/members/add?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Azure DevOps Service (https://dev.azure.com/xxxx), you could use [Members - Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/memberentitlementmanagement/members/add?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) REST API.

If you use Azure DevOps Server, the REST API to add members to projects and team is not documented. As a workaround, we can track this rest api by pressing `F12` in browser then select `Network`.

Sample:

```
POST http://TFS2019:8080/tfs/{Collection}/{project}/_api/_identity/AddIdentities?api-version=5.0

Request Body:

        {
            "newUsersJson": "[]",
            "existingUsersJson": "[\"55b98726-c6f5-48d2-976b-xxxxxx\"]",
            "groupsToJoinJson": "[\"7283653f-54b2-4ebf-86c3-xxxxxxx\"]",
            "aadGroupsJson": "[]"
        }
```

However as we can see we can only use the user and team/group GUID in the request json body. For the specific team/groups we can use the [REST APIs Projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/memberentitlementmanagement/members/add?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) and teams to get their GUID.
For the user, actually it's used the `TeamFoundationId`, the unique `TeamFoundationId` is automatically generated when a user is added to Azure DevOps Server. We cannot generate the ID with external tools.

So, to use that REST API, we need to get the `TeamFoundationId` of the specific user which you want to add it to the projects/teams.

Currently, no REST API to list `TeamFoundationId` of the users in Azure DevOps Server 2019, however we can get it with Client API:

Below sample for your reference to get the `TeamFoundationId` of a specific user: (It will also export the user list with their `TeamFoundationId` to `userlist.txt`)

```
using System;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Common;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace Getuserlist

{

    class Program

    {
        static void Main(string[] args)

        {

            TfsConfigurationServer tcs = new TfsConfigurationServer(new Uri("https://wsicads2019"));

            IIdentityManagementService ims = tcs.GetService<IIdentityManagementService>();

            TeamFoundationIdentity tfi = ims.ReadIdentity(IdentitySearchFactor.AccountName, "[DefaultCollection]\\Project Collection Valid Users", MembershipQuery.Expanded, ReadIdentityOptions.None);

            TeamFoundationIdentity[] ids = ims.ReadIdentities(tfi.Members, MembershipQuery.None, ReadIdentityOptions.None);

            using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter("userlist.txt"))

                foreach (TeamFoundationIdentity id in ids)

                {
                    if (id.Descriptor.IdentityType == "System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity" && id.UniqueName == "Domain\\User")

                    { Console.WriteLine("[{0},{1}]", id.UniqueName, id.TeamFoundationId); }

                    file.WriteLine("[{0},{1}]", id.UniqueName, id.TeamFoundationId);
                }

            var count = ids.Count(x => ids.Contains(x));
            Console.WriteLine(count);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked my reply? Is it helpful?